# SQL execute block using update

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to perform an `execute block` using an `update`. However I am getting an error.

The SQL shown here is similar to the real problem, but the `update` is much more complex. I need to use every declared `cust_id` into the `update` block.

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 

AS DECLARE VARIABLE CUSTOMER INT;

BEGIN
FOR
SELECT CUST_ID FROM CLIEN
 WHERE CUST_ID IN (1,2,3,4)
INTO :CUSTOMER

DO
BEGIN
UPDATE ORDERS
 SET STATUS='I'
WHERE CUST_ID=(SELECT CUST_ID
  FROM CUSTCONDITION
    WHERE CONDITION='OK' AND CUST_ID=:CUSTOMER)

DO BEGIN

END
END
END
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, why do you have a `SUSPEND` in your execute block, when you don't have a `RETURNS` clause? Also, there is no `FOR UPDATE` in Firebird PSQL, this is probably the cause of the error.

Comment: Hi Mark. I have edited the sql accordingly to your suggestion removing the `for` and `suspend` but I am still getting an error, the table is not updating. I don't know what error it is because I am executing the sql directly, no interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with you're getting no error because you're executing the SQL directly. Any method of executing SQL will report error messages, and that error is - at least on my machine - a token unknown error for `DO`, because `UPDATE` doesn't have a `DO BEGIN ... END` block. I recommend that you consult the [Firebird Language Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html) for valid syntax, instead of trying to throw things together and see if it works.

Comment: BTW: I don't really understand why you're doing this with an execute block, you could also do this with a single `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Hi Mark. I am using a basic custom application that will only execute the .txt with my SQL, when I am working with DML. If it works,I get a message successfully updated, otherwise I gen a error message, no details. Unfortunately  this a limitation I have at my work when doing DML. When doing DQL,  I have proper output messages.

Comment: What do you mean with DQL? In any case, it sounds like a serious limitation of the tooling you're using. I would recommend to use a local installation of Firebird to test things out with a normal query tool like DBeaver, FlameRobin, etc, or even ISQL.

Comment: I mean DQL by using SELECT commands

Comment: Select is also DML, just like an execute block. They all fall under the umbrella of DSQL (not DQL), or Dynamic SQL. What is inside an execute block is PSQL, or Procedural SQL.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. I thought that you call different when you simply query for results from when you actually change data in the database. Appreciate your explanations. Very useful.

Comment: Regarding my post question. In fact it was a syntax problem. Both you and Konstantin showed me the way to the correct SQL.

Comment: The distinction is DDL (Data Definition Language), eg `CREATE TABLE`, etc, vs DML (Data Manipulation Language), eg `SELECT`, `INSERT`, etc.

Comment: About "I don't really understand why you're doing this with an execute block..."  I have to use execute block in this problem. The real SQL  is more complex,  and I have to execute it for many customers ID in row. Using a single update will not work, I have tried...

Comment: If you can solve this with looping over a select and executing an update statement for each row, then you should be able to do this in a single update as well, but lets not dwell on that further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use do begin after our update statement

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 

AS DECLARE VARIABLE CUSTOMER INT;

BEGIN
FOR
SELECT CUST_ID FROM CLIEN
 WHERE CUST_ID IN (1,2,3,4)
INTO :CUSTOMER

DO
BEGIN
UPDATE ORDERS
 SET STATUS='I'
WHERE CUST_ID=(SELECT CUST_ID
  FROM CUSTCONDITION
    WHERE CONDITION='OK' AND CUST_ID=:CUSTOMER);

END
END
```